# How to find matching version of packages in VS Code using NPM?

Tags: c#, npm, visual-studio-code, .net-core

When we add a new package like 'Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection', we are getting a 'Template doesn't exist' error. We are getting the same error while adding any new packages using NPM in VS Code. How do we find the matching version for a new package?

Comment: Is this about C# and the dotnet core CLI or is this about JavaScript? Your mention of NPM kind of confuses me. Also if this is dotnet CLI when do you get the "Template doesn't exist error"

Comment: this is about c# and .net core.
In vs code,when I add a package through commandpalette,line of code is added in .csproj file like this:
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.0"/>   When I build the project I'm getting the template doesn't exist error

Comment: Ah I see. The problem is that this package only supports use in .NetStandard 1.6, .NetStandard 2.0 and .NetFramework 4.6.1, as stated [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alexinea.Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/)

Comment: So,Is it possible to implement autofac in .net core 2.2.3?

Comment: After further investigation: Which package version are you targeting? The one I linked is 2.2.0 which is almost 2 years old, but the 4.4.0 seems to be newer and could work. Also, when does it throw the error "Template doesn't exist"?

Comment: We have already tried to add 4.4.0....but it shows the same error